# how to remove list element

Tags: java, list

I am trying to remove list element but get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
at apollo.exercises.ch08_collections.Ex4_RemoveOdd.removeOdd(Ex4_RemoveOdd.java:25)
at apollo.exercises.ch08_collections.Ex4_RemoveOdd.main(Ex4_RemoveOdd.java:15)
```

here is my code

```
public class Ex4_RemoveOdd {
removeOdd(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21));
removeOdd(Arrays.asList(7,34,2,3,4,62,3));
public static void removeOdd(List<Integer> x){
    for(int i=0;i<=x.size()-1;i++){
        if (x.get(i)%2==0){
            System.out.println(x.get(i));
        }else{
            x.remove(i);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

So I make new class just to try to remove the element

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Integer> x = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21);
    x.remove(1);
}
```

but still have error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
at apollo.exercises.ch08_collections.Ex4_RemoveOdd.main(Ex4_RemoveOdd.java:14)
```

FYI:I try to solve this excercise https://github.com/thecodepath/intro_java_exercises/blob/master/src/apollo/exercises/ch08_collections/Ex4_RemoveOdd.java

Comment: Whatever you do, don't remove elements without using an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size list. Any call that will try to modify its size (by adding or removing elements) will throw this exception.

Use the `ArrayList` constructor that takes a collection as parameter instead.

```
removeOdd(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21)));
```

Also as noted in comments, it's safer (and highly recommended) to use the List's iterator to remove the elements from it.

Currently with your for-loop approach you will skip elements that you want to remove. For example when calling the method with the list `[1,2,3,5,8,13,21]`, the first iteration will remove `1` so all the elements will be shifted by one in the list. Then the value of `i` is `1`, the size of the list is `6` and `list.get(1)` will return `3` not `2` and so on.

At the end you will get `[2, 5, 8, 21]`, which is not what you want.

---

If you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), your code could be simplified as

```
public static void removeOdd(List<Integer> x){
    x.removeIf(i -> i%2 != 0);
}
```

Comment: need to insert the inferred arguments
so the code is
removeOdd(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21)));

Comment: @icemelt Depends on the version of Java you are using. For Java >= 7, it should work as the compiler can infer the type argument, otherwise yes you need to specify it.